# Yodlee : Invalid token in authorization header

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to test a GET call on the Yodless REST webservices.

I have tried following their instructions without success.

[image]

Looks like they have two tokens (Cobrand and User token)

Not sure which one of these tokens is an access token which I need to put in my authorization header.

But I have tried both and I am getting "Invalid Token in authorization header" for both of them as shown below.

Using "Cobrand token" as Authorization Header

[image]

Using "User token" as Authorization header

[image]

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

Looks like I need to set the authorization header as follows

```
{cobSession=XXX,userSession=YYY}
```

Once the above formatted data is sent as part of the payload I am able to get a successful response.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on same query for user login where we have only cobSession.
It was resolved by omitting the userSession from Authorization header:

```
{cobSession=08062013_1:0e40628790543eb3d7e7509ecee57b69e2e192e49d2f46dc6083e3eed5eb13f1bb40b61f002ef2fc35762990ca77161b2f1e5a40f0f846d5aa61}
```

Also make sure you are using the latest generated `userSession` & `cobSession`